# dynamic reconfigure changes at runtime

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The established way to use dynamic_reconfigure is through a .cfg file which cmake then will use to generate relevant .py scripts.

However, I have a device which can have different items to adjust which will be known at first runtime, but not consistently the same between uses. Is there a way to generate a Config class dynamically at runtime rather than through a saved .cfg script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12826/dynamic-reconfigure-changes-at-runtime/) by [dfseifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1721/dfseifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an [open enhancement ticket #3617](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/3617) to provide those kinds of features.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0